# Can't create multiple pages in Python/TkInter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm trying to create multiple pages in my Python program but don't know how. Here I have the first page of the program. I'm trying to make the buttons of this program link to another page. 
 
The goal is to create a base program using TkInter and Canvas, that integrates other sub-programs into the base program. Most of the answers have things such as `self`, or `_init_`, but that was not the way how I learned it.

```
from tkinter import *


tkw = Tk()
cvs = Canvas(width="800", height="600", background="#7ce577")


"""
FIRST ROW BUTTONS
"""
cvs.create_oval(50, 65, 250, 265, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
cvs.create_text(148, 161, text="L", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
btnScott = Button(tkw, text="Lee", font="Arial 16", command="scott", bg="#a0ccda")
btnScott.place(x=100, y=275, width="100", height="50")

cvs.create_oval(295, 65, 495, 265, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
cvs.create_text(395, 161, text="W", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
btnMan = Button(tkw, text="Wei Hong", font="Arial 16", command="man", bg="#a0ccda")
btnMan.place(x=345, y=275, width="100", height="50")

cvs.create_oval(540, 65, 740, 265, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
cvs.create_text(640, 161, text="R", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
btnRof = Button(tkw, text="Rofieq", font="Arial 16", command="rof", bg="#a0ccda")
btnRof.place(x=590, y=275, width="100", height="50")


"""
SECOND ROW BUTTONS
"""
cvs.create_oval(170, 340, 370, 540, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
cvs.create_text(270, 435, text="E", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
btnYang = Button(tkw, text="En Yang", font="Arial 16", command="yang", bg="#a0ccda")
btnYang.place(x=220, y=550, width="100", height="50")

cvs.create_oval(420, 340, 620, 540, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
cvs.create_text(520, 435, text="S", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
btnYun = Button(tkw, text="Sze Yun", font="Arial 16", command="yun", bg="#a0ccda")
btnYun.place(x=470, y=550, width="100", height="50")


cvs.pack()
cvs.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the question is fairly broad and suggest looking at tkinter examples using OOP design. The code in the answer below is common setup to see on stack. I have don some minor editing to add your code to 'PageOne'.

Comment: Thanks! But where is the code though?

Comment: I have just added it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not that familiar with OOP though but I'll try looking at other examples.

Comment: Your question didn't ask anything. What part of this program do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic example showing the use of two pages:

When the app is created, it in turn creates two pages and switches to `PageOne` using `self.show_frame(PageOne)`. When created, each page is passed a reference to the main app, which is maintained via `self.controller`. `self.controller` can be used by any child frame to access methods and data bellowing to the main app. Data or functionality needed by one or more pages would normally be contained within the main app, meaning all pages have access. In the example both pages use the main app method `show_frame`.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk 


class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.make_widget()

    def make_widget(self):
        self.cvs = Canvas(self, width="800", height="600", background="#7ce577")
        """
        FIRST ROW BUTTONS
        """
        self.cvs.create_oval(50, 65, 250, 265, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
        self.cvs.create_text(148, 161, text="L", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
        btnScott = Button(self.cvs, text="Lee", font="Arial 16", command="scott", bg="#a0ccda")
        btnScott.place(x=100, y=275, width="100", height="50")

        self.cvs.create_oval(295, 65, 495, 265, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
        self.cvs.create_text(395, 161, text="W", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
        btnMan = Button(self.cvs, text="Wei Hong", font="Arial 16", command="man", bg="#a0ccda")
        btnMan.place(x=345, y=275, width="100", height="50")

        self.cvs.create_oval(540, 65, 740, 265, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
        self.cvs.create_text(640, 161, text="R", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
        btnRof = Button(self.cvs, text="Rofieq", font="Arial 16", command="rof", bg="#a0ccda")
        btnRof.place(x=590, y=275, width="100", height="50")


        """
        SECOND ROW BUTTONS
        """
        self.cvs.create_oval(170, 340, 370, 540, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
        self.cvs.create_text(270, 435, text="E", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
        btnYang = Button(self.cvs, text="En Yang", font="Arial 16", command="yang", bg="#a0ccda")
        btnYang.place(x=220, y=550, width="100", height="50")

        self.cvs.create_oval(420, 340, 620, 540, fill="#a0ccda", outline="#a0ccdb")
        self.cvs.create_text(520, 435, text="S", font="Arial 60 bold", state="normal")
        btnYun = Button(self.cvs, text="Sze Yun", font="Arial 16", command="yun", bg="#a0ccda")
        btnYun.place(x=470, y=550, width="100", height="50")

        # demo button to change page
        btnChange = Button(self.cvs, text="Change", font="Arial 16",
                           command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageTwo),
                           bg="#a0ccda")
        btnChange .place(x=600, y=550, width="100", height="50")

        self.cvs.pack()

        def change_page(self):
            pass


class PageTwo(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller  
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.make_widget()

    def make_widget(self):
        ttk.Label(self, text='This is page two').grid(padx=(20,20), pady=(20,20))
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Previous Page',
                             command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.title('Multi-Page Test App')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer copies code from another answer but is presented as if you wrote it. You should link to the original answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley it has been a while can you comment the link to the answer and I will be happy to link it above

Comment: Can we then remove the -1?

Comment: P.S. can't remember posting this, but plagiarism was not the intent.